# Genexus: Error CS0234 llamando a un External Object con un stored procedure in Gx Ev 3 U5

Tags: genexus

Estoy tratando de llamar a un Stored Procedure desde [genexus](/questions/tagged/genexus), en la versión Evolution 3 Upgrade 5 y no me genera el código [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) del `External Object`, por lo tanto me da:

> error CS0234: El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'SdtdynQuery'
>   no existe en el espacio de nombres 'GeneXus.Programs' (¨falta una
>   referencia de ensamblado?)

¿Qué puede estar faltando?

---

Aclaración. Luego de jugar bastante, descubrí que si llamo al External Object desde un evento en la transacción, lo ejecuta perfectamente, pero si lo llamo desde una regla, ahí da el error.

Les paso el código de como lo estoy llamando:

```
&sp2.IncrementNumerator("CodigoEmpresa", EmpresaCodigo) if EmpresaCodigo.IsEmpty() on BeforeInsert;
```

Muchas gracias, Ariel

Comment: Bienvenido @ArielLaniado, podrías agregar mas información como que intentaste hacer hasta ahora, poner alguna porción de código, cuanto más aportes más fácil sera que alguien pueda ayudar.

Comment: Ahí agregue una nota a la pregunta.

Comment: @ArielLaniado Si disparas otra regla con las mismas condiciones, digamos un `msg()` o una llamada a un Procedure, ¿se ejecuta? Porque tal vez el problema no sea el external object, y esté en las condiciones.

Answer (score 3):

Ariel, si el external object es un stored procedure, es decir corresponde a un stored procedure en la BD, asegúrate de que ese external object tenga la propiedad `Type = Stored Procedure` y que los tipos de los parámetros sean tipos básicos, no sdts.

Si eso está correcto y sigue dando el error, ayudaría que mandes el `xpz` del external object.

Comment: Ahí agregue una nota a la pregunta.

Comment: Si se ejecuta el StoreProcedure desde una Procedure se ejecuta sin problemas (el código C# generado es diferente).